# Scala passing a reference to this class

Tags: class, scala

I have a class, with multiple methods and members.  When I create an instance of this class, I create an instance of another class within the first class.  Some of the methods in this second class require to know which instance of the first class is running.  Currently, I am trying to pass "this" into the argument that accepts type firstClass.  What am I doing wrong?  Again, I simply want the second class instance knowing what first class instance it belongs to so that it can call public methods and members from it.

EDIT: Code example:

```
def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit = {
  val objectOne = new classOne
}

class classOne {
  val mutableBuffer = mutable.Buffer[String]
  val objectTwo = new classTwo

  objectTwo.doThis(this)
}

class classTwo {
  def doThis (exA:classOne) = {
    exA.mutableBuffer += "Adding text to a Buffer in object One"
  }
}
```

Comment: It might help if you give some code demonstrating what you're trying to do, and what specifically doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self-typing is often the cleanest solution here

```
class Bippy {
  outer =>
  ...
  class Bop {
    def demoMethod() = println(outer)
  }
  ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

The example code changes everything, this clearly isn't about inner classes.  I believe your problem is in this line:

```
val mutableBuffer = mutable.Buffer[String]
```

It isn't doing what you think it's doing, `mutableBuffer` is now pointing to the `mutable.Buffer` singleton, it isn't actually an instance of a `Buffer`

Instead, try one of these two:

```
val mutableBuffer = mutable.Buffer[String]()
//or
val mutableBuffer = mutable.Buffer.empty[String]
```

You should also stick to the convention of starting class/singleton/type names with an uppercase letter, turning your example code into:

```
import collection.mutable.Buffer

def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit = {
  val one = new ClassOne()
}

class ClassOne {
  val mutableBuffer = Buffer.empty[String]
  val two = new ClassTwo()

  two.doThis(this)
}

class ClassTwo {
  def doThis(one: ClassOne) = {
    one.mutableBuffer += "Adding text to a Buffer in object One"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to rewrite your answer. I actually tried the buffer declared as Buffer[String]() and its still not happy.  I took your considerations with the code style... thanks for pointing them out.  I'm going to look up the singleton term as I haven't consciously used it before, and its something I should probably understand.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

I had to make some superficial changes to your example code in order to make it run:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class classOne {
  val mutableBuffer : mutable.Buffer[String] = new mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]
  val objectTwo = new classTwo

  objectTwo.doThis(this)
}

class classTwo {
  def doThis (exA : classOne) = {
    exA.mutableBuffer += "Adding text to a Buffer in object One"
  }
}

val objectOne = new classOne
println(objectOne.mutableBuffer(0))
```

But it works as expected. The `classTwo` object is able to modify the `classOne` object. Do you need something beyond this functionality?

Comment: No I don't, thanks Dan!  I am going to play around with this a bit.  My code is more complicated than the example that I gave... but the concept is the same.  Let me see if i can get this to work!